# Small animation works only with .data?

Tags: javascript

I made this small animation so I can practice, its purpose is to add the last letter to the beginning of the word.
I've thought that it should work with ".innerTEXT" instead of .data too, but it doesn't. Can you explain why and how does .data work? On w3schools I've learnt that .data returns a URL, so wouldn't this be supposed to work with .innerTEXT?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
const div = document.getElementById('1');
const node = div.childNodes[0];
let text = node.data;

setInterval(() => {
text=text[text.length - 1] + text.substring(0, text.length-1);
node.data = text;
}, 100);
});
```

```html
<div id="1">asdf</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the working example with the `innerText` below.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
const div = document.getElementById('1');
let text = div.innerText;

setInterval(() => {
    text=text[text.length - 1] + text.substring(0, text.length-1);
    div.innerText = text;
}, 100);
});
```

```html
<div id="1">asdf</div>
```

You can also do this with the node like you did, but you should use `textContent`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
const div = document.getElementById('1');
const node = div.childNodes[0];
let text = node.textContent;

setInterval(() => {
    text=text[text.length - 1] + text.substring(0, text.length-1);
    node.textContent = text;
}, 100);
});
```

```html
<div id="1">asdf</div>
```

Comment: It's working, I'll accept it as correct. Which one would be better to use?

Comment: Updated with the another approach. I'd use `div.innerText` . I don't see a need to introduce node here.

Comment: You can have some read here also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent